# SQl cross pivot query error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio:

I have the following cross tab query I'm currently creating, this is what I have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE #Months
(UserID int,
ModuleID int,
Passed bit,
Name nvarchar(255),
Company nvarchar(50),
LanguageID nvarchar(10),
CodeRegisteredWith nvarchar(50),
TotalLoggedInDuration int,
Region int,
IsAdmin bit,
IsRep bit,
IsRetailer bit,
IsTeamLeader bit,
dateregistered date,
total int,
usertotal int,
complete int,
January int, february int, march int, april int, may int, June int, July int,
August int, September int, October int, November int, December int)

SELECT
   [1] January,
   [2] February,
   [3] March,
   [4] April,
   [5] May,
   [6] June,
   [7] July,
   [8] August,
   [9] September,
   [10] October,
   [11] November,
   [12] December
   FROM
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,0,Convert(smalldatetime,[dateregistered],120))as months
  FROM #Temp WITH(NOLOCK)
) d
pivot 
(
   SUM(complete)
   for months in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) p
```

This query is meant to populate 12 new fields (months) with "passed" data:

So in theory you have 12 columns one record each cell will have a sum of how many users passed in that month.

But I'm currently adding and testing as this is part of a massive stored procedure using virtual tables.  when I run this procedure all the others work but this fails and complains:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GRAPHMainQuery, Line 127
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to smalldatetime.
>   Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GRAPHMainQuery, Line 127
>   The incorrect value "1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Nvarchar to smalldatetime? I've already stored this as a date in my #table, I'm even using convert() I just don't understand why this is complaining?

Comment: Check the values of your dateregistered column in your #temp table. You're getting the error message because one or more of the values can not be converted to a smalldatetime. Make sure the values are formatted as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss - also make sure that you don't have values that are invalid on SQL Server, such as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Comment: yeh thats the 1st thing i checked seems all fine,  i suspect it may be the select before the pivot treating them as nvarchar columns and the dateregistered as a date so it throws the error cannot convert. maybe if i cast to an nvar? hmm not sure this is strange

Comment: Ah, now I get it - DATEADD(MONTH,0,Convert(smalldatetime,[dateregistered],120)) returns a smalldatetime value, not a nvarchar. Actually, what you need is just the month number, right? This means you should just use MONTH(Convert(datetime,[dateregistered],120)) which returns an integer, that can be compared to the pivot column list.

Comment: argghhhh! works hahaha i thought it was that damn pivot comparison! many thanks Dan, post an answer and ill upvote an confirm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
MONTH(Convert(datetime,[dateregistered],120)) as months
```

to get the month number (returns an integer). DATEADD(...) returns a datetime/smalldatetime value, which can not be compared to the [1]...[12] month number columns in the PIVOT statement.